# Unity IoC generic class

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have the following UnitOfWork class:

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork where TContext : IContext, new()
{
    private readonly IContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new TContext();
    }

    public UnitOfWork(IContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    ...
}
```

and I want to register it to an IoC container using Unity but I'm not sure how to do it. I tried to do something like this:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType(typeof(UnitOfWork<>), new InjectionConstructor(new GenericParameter ("TContext")));
...
```

but it didn't work. Any idea how to do it?

Tnx.

Comment: Why does this class have 2 public constructors?

Comment: Since having multiple constructors is a design smell because it leads to ambiguity. Why does the unit of work need to create a `TContext`, when it will be supplied from the outside?

Comment: Maybe it is a bad design but it doesn't matter.My question still stands and I would appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: Prevent having multiple constructors as [explained here](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the Resolve method (or another object dependent on UnitOfWork), but at resolution time, you do have to specify the type.  `container.Resolve(typeof(UnitOfWork<>))` can't work.

If you try and resolve `UnitOfWork<ContextImplmentation>` and a `ContextImplemenation` instance is registered in the container, you'll get a `UnitOfWork<ContextImplmentation>` with that context implementation value injected.

If you don't have anything of that type registered (or overridden in some fashion), you'll get an error, because Unity won't know which specific implementation of an IContext to use.

Comment: Tnx. Nick. The thing is that Steven was right: if I wan't to use IoC I have to get rid of the constructor which has no parameter.